# Send image from flask server to android app

Tags: java, android

Hi i am new to android apps, i want to send an image as a response to a HttpPost request. I am trying to send an image on response from a flask python server to an android client and update an ImageView. Any suggestions ?

Flask server code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
import werkzeug
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
#import single_image_inference as single_image
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from base64 import encodebytes
import time




app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/x', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])    
def get_response_image(image_path):
    return send_file(image_path, mimetype='image/jpg')
    

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

Android Client Code :

```
    void postRequest(String postUrl, RequestBody postBody) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(postUrl)
                .post(postBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // Cancel the post on failure.
                call.cancel();

                // In order to access the TextView inside the UI thread, the code is executed inside runOnUiThread()
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Something went wrong:" + " " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }




            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

i am receiving the following

```
D/skia: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'
I/e.myapplicatio: Background young concurrent copying GC freed 2321(176KB) AllocSpace objects, 16(2200KB) LOS objects, 31% free, 4199KB/6107KB, paused 69us total 658.626ms
```